# Running gazebo and moveit in docker container with ubuntu 22.04 and ros2 humble

Tags: docker, ubuntu-22.04, ros2, gazebo-simu

I am trying to run gazebo simulations of xarm robot inside the docker container, but I get black screen even if I just run gazebo itself.
[image]

Here is a dockerfile from where I created the image:

```
# Use Ubuntu 22.04 as the base image
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Set environment variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV ROS_DISTRO=humble
ENV ament_cmake_DIR=/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/share/ament_cmake/cmake

# Update the package lists and install necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    lsb-release \
    locales \
    sudo \
    git \
    wget 
    

# Set the locale to avoid any locale-related issues
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

# Add the ROS 2 apt repository
RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list

# Update the package lists again and install ROS 2 Humble
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ros-$ROS_DISTRO-desktop \
    ros-$ROS_DISTRO-ros-base

# Install additional dependencies for rosdep
RUN apt-get install -y python3-rosdep python3-colcon-common-extensions xorg

# Initialize rosdep and update
RUN rosdep init && rosdep update

# Create the ROS workspace
RUN mkdir -p /root/ros2_ws/src

# Clone the xarm_ros2 repository
RUN cd /root/ros2_ws/src && \
    git clone --recursive -b $ROS_DISTRO https://github.com/xArm-Developer/xarm_ros2.git && \
    cd /root/ros2_ws/src/xarm_ros2/ && \
    git pull && \
    git submodule sync && \
    git submodule update --init --remote

# Clone the gazebo_ros2_control repository
RUN cd /root/ros2_ws/src && \
    git clone https://github.com/ros-controls/gazebo_ros2_control.git

# Install the dependency
RUN apt-get install -y ros-$ROS_DISTRO-ament-cmake

# Update rosdep and install
RUN cd /root/ros2_ws/src && \
    rosdep update && \
    rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y

# Build the ROS workspace
RUN cd /root/ros2_ws && \
    . /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.sh && \
    colcon build

# Set up the entrypoint
CMD ["bash"]
```

I searched internet and asked chatgpt to help, couldn't solve and stopped at this:

```
docker run -it --gpus all --device /dev/snd:/dev/snd   --privileged   -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY   -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix   -e PULSE_SERVER=unix:${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/pulse/native   -v ${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/pulse/native:${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/pulse/native   -v ~/.config/pulse/cookie:/root/.config/pulse/cookie  -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/home/$(id -un)/.Xauthority -e XAUTHORITY=/home/$(id -un)/.Xauthority ros2-humble:latest
```

Seems like I am missing something or building the docker image wrong.